# Show the Chat box in the sidebar for Public Beta sites

Tags: feature-request, chat, beta-phase, sidebar

There's usually a sidebar link to the chat of all SE 2.0 sites on the main/meta pages.

However, this link doesn't show up in the sidebar for public beta sites:

[image]

You can see this on [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/). For reference, the [Meta Site](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/) does include the chat box.

Since the element is vertical there's really no harm in "wasting space", so I can't see why the chat link is excluded. While the space wasted is minimal, the chat box does make chat a *lot* more visible and lets you check if a site's chat is *active* as well.

Can Public Beta sites please get a chat box in the sidebar like all other sites? Chat is a great way to encourage "regulars" and deepen engagement between users, which is especially helpful for a growing community. Beta is one of the most important times for building community, so it seems extremely counterproductive to hide chat from Beta users.

Comment: Not all graduate sites have the chat box on the side. Mostly just the Meta sites do.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA which ones don't? The only sites I know which don't have the chat box are the trilogy sites

Comment: Hmmm I see that now.

Answer (score 5):

Chat does in fact appear in the sidebar, but for some reason, it just doesn't show up unless you are viewing a question. On the main page, it seems to be hidden. I observe this behavior on [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) as well as [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com).

Below is a screenshot of chat as it looks to me while viewing one of the questions on Cognitive Sciences:

---

[image: Cognitive Sciences Sidebar]

---

Here is the same sidebar view of chat while viewing a question on Project Management:

---

[image: PMSE Sidebar]

---

Oddly, on StackOverflow, I viewed several questions, as well as the main page, and I didn't see chat at all, and on Programmers SE, I see only the opposite: Chat is visible on the main page, but not when viewing a question.

Thus, it seems that chat *is there*. It just only appears some of the time.

Comment: It seems that the site-stats module replaces Chat (site stats isn't on questions, while the chat box is)

Comment: It seems that the pattern is different on some sites. Like Programmers SE, for instance, only showed chat on the main page, at least for me, while on the beta sites I only saw chat on the questions pages.